# Positive part of Cauchy sequence of Sobolev functions is again Cauchy

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $p\geq 1$ and consider the space $W^{1,p}(B)$ where $B\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the standard unit ball. Moreover, let $f_{k} \in C^{\infty}(B)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $W^{1,p}(B)$ of smooth function. How can one deduce that also $f_{k}^{+}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $W^{1,p}(B)$, where $f_{k}^{+}$ are defined by
$$
f_{k}^{+}(x) = \text{max}\{f_{k}(x),0\}?
$$

Greetings.

Comment: In other words, $F_:f\mapsto |f|$ is a continuous self-map of $W^{1,p}(B)$. One way to show it is approximating with $F_\epsilon:f\mapsto |f^2+\epsilon^2|^{1/2}$ and letting $\epsilon\to0$

Comment: I think Pietro meant "positive part $f^+=\max\{f,0\}$", and not "absolute value $|f|$". Anyway, this is true because the composition $F(f)$ of $1$-Lipschitz maps $F$ satisfying $F(0)=0$ and Sobolev maps $f\in W^{1,p}$ (including $p=1$) is again Sobolev, with $\|F(f)\|_{W^{1,p}}\leq \|f\|_{W^{1,p}}$

Comment: And as Pietro mentioned, the proof goes by approximation (of $F=\lim F_\epsilon$)

Comment: I have fixed a misprint in the title. Sobolev was as much a real person as Cauchy.

Comment: More generally, the following is true: if $\phi:{\mathbb R}\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$ is globally Lipschitz, then $f\mapsto\phi\circ f$ maps $W^{1,p}(B)$ into itself continuously. In particular, if $(f_k)_k$ is Cauchy, then so is $(\phi\circ f_k)_k$.

Comment: If my memory is correct, Pietro's argument, which works for every Lipschitz function, is due to G. Stampacchia.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$
\bigl\vert\vert f_{k+l}(x)\vert-\vert f_{k}(x)\vert\bigr\vert\le 
\vert f_{k+l}(x)-f_{k}(x)\vert
$
and thus
$$
\Vert\vert f_{k+l}\vert-\vert f_{k}\vert\Vert_{W^{1,1}}
\le 
\Vert f_{k+l}- f_{k}\Vert_{L^{1}}+\Vert \nabla{\vert f_{k+l}\vert}
-\nabla{\vert f_{k}\vert}\Vert_{L^{1}}.
$$
Now, let us calculate $\nabla \vert f\vert$, say for $f\in C^1$. We claim that we have
$$
\nabla \vert f\vert=S(f) \nabla f, \quad S(f)=\mathbf 1(f>0)-\mathbf 1(f<0).
\label{1}\tag{1}$$
Note that the function $S(f)$ is bounded measurable and that the product makes sense, even if you have only $\nabla f\in L^1$. Let us prove our claim: with brackets of duality and $\phi\in C^\infty_c$, we have
\begin{multline}
\langle \nabla \vert f\vert, \phi\rangle=-\int\vert f\vert \nabla \phi dx=-\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0_+}\int(f^2+\epsilon^2)^{1/2} \nabla \phi dx=
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0_+}\int(f^2+\epsilon^2)^{-1/2} f(\nabla f)  \phi dx
\\
=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0_+}\int(f^2+\epsilon^2)^{-1/2} f(\nabla f)  \phi dx
=\int S(f) (\nabla f) \phi dx,
\end{multline}
proving \eqref{1}, using Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem. I feel a bit uncomfortable to extend this formula to $f\in W^{1,1}$, but it might be a first step.

Comment: This is about $\lvert f\rvert$, but I guess one can use it to handle $f^+ = \frac1 2(f + \lvert f\rvert)$.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, identity (1) for a general $f \in W^{1,1}$ is a straightforward application of the ACL characterisation of weakly differentiable functions, is it not?